# Create a moodle course which links directly to a SCORM pacakge

Tags: moodle

I have installed a moodle environment and uploaded a SCORM package. I run all my courses through SCORM therefore the additional activities are not needed.

Is there any way I can make the Course button link directly into the SCORM package to cut the additional clicking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple options:

- Select the "single activity" course format: This prevents the /course/view.php page from appearing. Users still have to click a button to enter the SCORM activity, but takes clicks and page views out of the UX. This option can be selected in the course settings.
- Customize: Create a version of the SCORM activity that launches without requiring the user to click the entry button on the SCORM activity page. This requires replicating what occurs when the the user clicks the entry button on the SCORM page, but is possible.

Hope one of these is helpful - good luck w/ it!